# pyspark dataframe filtering on multiple columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which looks like below

df

```
num11   num21 
10     10
20     30 
5      25
```

I am filtering above dataframe on all columns present, and selecting rows with number greater than 10 [no of columns can be more than two]

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
col_list = df.schema.names
df_fltered = df.where(col(c) >= 10 for c in col_list)
```

desired output is :

```
num11    num21
10       10
20       30
```

How can we achieve filtering on multiple columns using iteration on column list as above. [all efforts are appriciated]

**[error i reveive is : condition should be string or column]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce` to combine the column conditions, to simulate an all condition, for instance, you can use `reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, ...)`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce

df.where(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y,  (F.col(x) >= 10 for x in df.columns))).show()
+-----+-----+
|num11|num21|
+-----+-----+
|   10|   10|
|   20|   30|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried above logic as                                                                     df_pass = df3.where(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y,  (col(x).cast('integer') == 2 | col('status1').cast('string') == 'present in source only' for x in columns1)))           but i am receiving error when i am passing 2 columns                                               Error received is  "Py4JException: Method or([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist"

Comment: You need to wrap the comparison in parenthesis. `df3.where(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, ((col(x).cast('integer') == 2) | (col('status1').cast('string') == 'present in source only') for x in columns1)))` because of the higher operator precedence of `|` compared to `==`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, if you not averse to some sql-like snippets of code, the following should work:

```
df.where("AND".join(["(%s >=10)"%(col) for col in col_list]))
```